# Custom Watchkit Glance Layout

Tags: ios, ios8, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there a way to change the layout of my watch app's glance view? I can't delete or change the group from the default layout. Not even hiding or unmarking the "Installed" from one of the groups just forces the remaining group onto the top left.

I'm hoping to create a full screen image for my **Glance**, leaving room where necessary for the page indicator at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to the templates that are provided for the Glance view. As you've noted, however, you can populate your own controls in the `WKInterfaceGroup` instances. Otherwise, you're stuck with what Apple has provided.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I was hoping there was just something non-obvious I missed, and that Google wasn't telling me be about it.  I suppose I can just hope that the situation changes after June 8.

Comment: I have the same impression, but does anybody know how to prove it? Client just says "but the activity app has full screen glance" (the circle progress).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limitation on the **Glance**, you can not really do too much in the **Glance**. That's why Apple has already limited you when you implement the interface. Try to get something that really interested based on different needs of users. That's all you need to do.

1. The **Glance** should be used to post something interested to the user. It means that **Glance** is read only
2. The **Glance** can not be scroll up and down because it's aimed to fit with one page

Comment: Thanks Lucas.  I do understand these limitations, and my question wasn't an attempt to work around these.  I do not intend to put interactive elements in the Glance screen nor make it scroll, simply change the layout of the default template.

Comment: I am saying that because of the limitation, you are forbidden to change the layout in storyboard. They want you to use the vertical layout and make it simple.

Comment: And I am telling you, make it simple and feed different data based on different users' need. That's what you need to do. Not quite sure why you voted it down.

Comment: I voted it down because it didn't address the question and went on an unrelated tangent.  I don't know why you voted my question down.